# ImportError for BeautifulSoap even when installed

Tags: python, pip, importerror

I've been trying to import BeautifulSoap (Beautiful Soap 4, not 3) with

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoap`

but I keep getting an ImportError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'BeautifulSoap'
```

I've already installed BeautifulSoap4 with pip, through `pip install bs4` and `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall beautifulsoup4`. For some reason, `pip install beautifulsoap4` gives me:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement beautifulsoap4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for beautifulsoap4
```

Anyways, just importing bs4 with `import bs4` gives me no errors. None of my Python files are named bs4.py or beautifulsoap.py or anything of the sort. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I've been searching for the reason for the past hour :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot. For some dumb reason I thought the library was called Beautiful**Soap**. Thanks guys <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `pip install bs4`  nor `pip install beautifulsoap4` installs BeautifulSoup (Soup != Soap)

The command is 
`pip install beautifulsoup4`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Check [Docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

If you search the names by pip, you can see:
    pip search bs4:

> bs4 (0.0.1)         - Dummy package for Beautiful Soup

```
pip search beautifulsoup4
```

> beautifulsoup4 (4.6.0)        - Screen-scraping library

Comment: @ShawnLee read the command carefully, it's not *soap*, it is `beautifulsoup4`

Comment: Thanks a bunch... makes me feel really stupid to have wasted the last hour of my life because I thought soap==soup!

Answer (score 1):

You have typo with `BeautifulSoup`

Correct is `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`